# SpecFlow: To run feature file with multiple scenarios several times with different parameters

Tags: specflow

I'm wondering why we can run Scenario several times with different parameters but cannot run whole feature file with different parameters.

Our feature files consists of many scenarios and feature file corresponds to Test Case, but when we need to run the same feature file, but with different parameter(s) then whole feature file has to be duplicated... Is there any possibility to parametrize whole feature file?

Comment: Can you post one of the scenarios? Why can't you use a Scenario Outline?

Comment: Because we have feature file with e.g. 40 scenarios and that all scenarios is a one test case, and parameters should be defined for many of this scenarios simultaniously.

Comment: Each scenario should be a single test case. Each scenario should be executable on its own. If this isn't how you are setting it up, then you not quite using scenarios for their intended purpose.

Comment: in this case they will be too long and not conveniant for human reading. What do you mean "on it's own".The actually executable on its own. But we have test cases with many scenarios(scenario is a step for test case), and also scenarios are reusable in different .feature files. How does it contradicts your conception?

Comment: So, do you mean, for example, the scenario where a user registers must run before the scenario where the user writes a blog post, since you just be a registered user to write a blog post?

Comment: You might be asking the wrong question. Scenarios should not require other scenarios. You might want to read [How Do I Write Cucumber Tests That Build On Previous Features?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58308477/3092298).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you are aware of the Scenario Outline.

> The Scenario Outline keyword can be used to run the same Scenario
>   multiple times, with different combinations of values

---

Copying and pasting scenarios to use different values quickly becomes tedious and repetitive as shown in the below example:

```
Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
   Given User is at the Home Page
   And Navigate to LogIn Page
   When User enter "testuser_1" and "Test@123"
   And Click on the LogIn button
   Then Successful LogIN message should display

Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
   Given User is at the Home Page
   And Navigate to LogIn Page
   When User enter "testuser_2" and "Test@153"
   And Click on the LogIn button
   Then Successful LogIN message should display
```

We can collapse these two similar scenarios into a Scenario Outline.

Scenario outlines allow us to more concisely express these scenarios through the use of a template with < > - delimited parameters:

```
Scenario Outline: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
   Given User is at the Home Page
   And Navigate to LogIn Page
   When User enter <username> and <password>
   And Click on the LogIn button
   Then Successful LogIN message should display
Examples:
| username   | password |
| testuser_1 | Test@123 |
| testuser_2 | Test@153 |
```

A Scenario Outline must contain an Examples (or Scenarios) section. Its steps are interpreted as a template which is never directly run. Instead, the Scenario Outline is run once for each row in the Examples section beneath it (not counting the first header row).

The steps can use <> delimited parameters that reference headers in the examples table. Cucumber will replace these parameters with values from the table before it tries to match the step against a step definition.

Comment: please see me answer-question by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883996/yes-i-know-about-scenario-outline